# Creating Multiple Views in one SQL file

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ddl, sql-view

I am trying to create an Install Script for installing Multiple Views at one time. I have tried several suggestions found through out  the net with no success. The script will install 6 views and an index.

```
USE [DB_NAme]
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
```

at top of script

Things I have tried:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  CREATE VIEW [schema].[View_Name]
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

error as
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
      CREATE VIEW [schema].[View_Name]
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ERR CODE
    END CATCH
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

with a few other variations.

Looking for a way to several CREATE views in one .sql file:

checks for and drops/creates indexes
checks for and DROPS views
creates views.. 7 of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just separate the definitions with `GO`:

```
CREATE VIEW view1
    SELECT . . .
GO

CREATE VIEW view2
    SELECT . . .
GO

. . .
```